# Where are emails being created?

Tags: email, email-alert

Salesforce is sending out mainly reminder emails on tasks, is there a way to find out where they are being created? I want to know if there is a way to see what class, flow, or something else is sending the emails?

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.  You should show (use [edit]) what you are observing via screen shots

Comment: The only way is to review all your workflow / process builder / Flow / Apex to see if anything is sending email.

Answer (score 1):

Use Email Logs to Monitor Emails Sent from Salesforce

After you send an email, Salesforce creates an email record to track the email and store its content. The activity feed includes a link to that email. If you sent email to a contact or lead, each of those records includes a link to the email.

For emails that don’t include any contact or lead records as recipients in the To field, the email and the feed item are created for the record specified in the Related To field when you sent the email

1. Open either the record that was originally open when you wrote the email or the record for the contact or lead you sent it to.
2. To find the email in Past Activity, click the Activity tab
3. To open the email’s task record, where you can view the message and related details, click the email link. And if you use Automatic BCC, you can find the sent email in your inbox.

For more reference, refer this :- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_monitor_emails_sent_from_salesforce.htm&type=5

Comment: The email log does not tell you what workflow / process / Flow sent the email, so it will not help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to work backwards and leverage VS Code to search against all your metadata.

For setting up VS Code - I'd suggest looking through existing [trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quickstart-vscode-salesforce/start-vscode). You'll want to pull down the metadata related to any potential area you're interested in. The below should cover the major automations (apex, flow/process builder/workflow, email alerts, email templates)

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "ApexClass,Flow,EmailTemplate,Workflow"`

Now, you'll have to work backwards and leverage the ability to search against all the relevant metadata within VS Code (Ctrl+Shift+F)

1. For the email you're interested in, look at the content. Find the relevant email template in Salesforce that it's based on. If you can't easily find it (or have lots of templates), just do a search across all the metadata in VS Code using some static text from the template. That should give you the email template (or apex code if it's not using a template)
2. Assuming you have the template, now you want to leverage the template name and do another search all. This should give you all the locations this template is being used. Ex. Email Alert
3. Assuming you find the Email Alert, now you'll use the name again to do another search. This should tell you what is triggering the email alert. Workflow rule, flow, etc.

If the above yields no results, then it's likely a "standard" email. Put another way, a standard notification provided by Salesforce. This might not apply in your situation, but, worth pointing out for other scenarios (ex. Whens someone assigns you a task).